# php5. Would be in some way possible to run 2 functions in parallel?

Tags: php, function, parallel-processing

Is there a way or php5 library to run functions in parallel?

I have a script like this:

```
function test() {
    sleep(5);
    return date("r");
}
$a = test();
$b = test();
echo $a . "\n" . $b . "\n";
```

The current output is

```
Wed, 15 Jan 2020 12:07:17 +0100
Wed, 15 Jan 2020 12:07:22 +0100
```

The output that I would like instead to get is:

```
Wed, 15 Jan 2020 12:08:24 +0100
Wed, 15 Jan 2020 12:08:24 +0100
```

**Note**: *test() function is only an example. The function that I need to run in parallel is more complex and in charge to read different portion of a file in parallel (instead of in sequence).*

Comment: Never seen PHP supporting multithreading. To read file in parallel, you can instead `file_get_contents()` and move pointer variables in parallel.

Comment: Yes there is a way in php for multi threading but the only drawback is, that oinly console app use it, you can read more on pthreads here https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php

Comment: Mhm @vivek_23... but in this case I have to run 2 different script in parallel (and this I know it's possible through proc_open capability) whereas I need to run 2 functions, in parallel. I need, as example, to read file "a.txt" having a function that read from byte 0 to 10 and __in parallel__ another function reading from byte 11 to 20.
Or, with a different example (forget about file parsing), 2 functions that computes the result of 1+1 and the result of 2+2. Both has to be executed in parallel.

Comment: @StefanoRadaelli You can look at what blackxero suggested. I meant in terms of reading the entire file and moving pointers from whatever char sequence you like.